# cannot pass info to paypal saying cannot be processed

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to pass the following information to paypal and it s saying "it cannot be processed at this time. Can anyone please tell me where going wrong. I am using sandbox environment to test at the minute.

The form is being submitted using a jquery submit form which relates to the ID

```
<

form action="https://sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="PayPalForm" >

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="subtotal"        value="20.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="business"        value="testemail@test.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="paymentaction"   value="sale" />
<input type="hidden" name="template"        value="TemplateD" />
<input type="hidden" name="return"      value="success.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code"   value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="address_override"    value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number"     value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity"        value="<?php echo $chairno; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom"      value="<?php echo $custom; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="first_name"      value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="last_name"       value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="address1"        value="<?php echo $add1; ?> <?php echo $add2; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="city"        value="<?php echo $city; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="zip"         value="<?php echo $post; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="country"     value="<?php echo $country; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="billing_first_name"      value="<?php echo $bill_fname; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="billing_last_name"       value="<?php echo $bill_lname; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="billing_address1"        value="<?php echo $bill_add1; ?> <?php echo $bill_add2; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="billing_city"        value="<?php echo $bill_city; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="billing_zip"         value="<?php echo $bill_post; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="billing_country"     value="<?php echo $country; ?>" />      
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="ipn.php" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subtotal`, `template` and all `billing_xxxxx` parameters are PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution parameters. Yet `cmd=_xclick` belongs to Website Payments Standard.

What's the PayPal product you're trying to integrate?
If it's Website Payments Standard, use `amount` for the amount to be charged and drop `template`.

If it's Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution, set the value of `cmd` of `_hosted-payment` and change the `action` to `https://securepayments.paypal.com/cgi-bin/acquiringweb`.